# Part of unity text field jittery/smudging in Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

My team has made an application in Unity3D with MRTK for the Hololens 2. Our main menu inside the application does not use a Canvas, but includes Quads to display pictures and Text Mesh Pro's 3D text fields. I have found that, while this menu is open, several elements like the top-left corner picture and *part of* the text fields are jittery when you hold your head steady. When you nod your head, the affected parts of the text seem to lag behind so that they end up lower or higher than the text that remains steady.

The cutoff point between stable and unstable text is always the same. There is a central area that is stable. Text that is too high, or too far to the left or right in unstable. The division is in the middle of the letters (For example, the top-most part of the capital letter S is unstable, while the smaller letter m is stable.) It does not matter if the viewport is centered on the center or the side of the menu. Other objects in the menu, such as buttons, that are further outside the center, are still stable.

I'm aware that there can be problems with hologram stability, but I do not understand why only part of the same textfield are affected. I can't include screenshots or videos because the effect doesn't show up in screencaptures of the Hololens.

Does anyone know what could be causing part of an object to be unstable in the Hololens, and what might be done about it?

Edit: I made an edited screenshot to try and recreate the visual effect seen in the Hololens:
[image: Top: Regular view, Bottom: display when moving head, recreated]

Comment: In this case, a screenshot could speak a thousand words.

Comment: @frankhermes It doesn't show up in screen captures of the Hololens, I cobbled together an edited screenshot that recreates the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to depth reprojection. Text doesn't write to the depth buffer by default, which can lead to instability. MRTK have some tips, including specifically for TMPro:[Depth buffer sharing in Unity](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/hologram-stabilization.html#depth-buffer-sharing-in-unity)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out. Will mark the answer if it works, will be a little before I can check.

Comment: A bit belated but: Changing the shader as recommended worked. Thanks.